# Building parallel hdf5 with cygwin

Tags: parallel-processing, cygwin, h5py, hdf

I recently attempted to install parallel hdf5-1.10.1 from source with cygwin 2.8.2 and stumbled into a "SIG_SETMASK undeclared" error during make. I wanted to use h5py to write hdf files in parallel (in windows environment).

I tried to follow the instructions from https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/release_docs/INSTALL_parallel

First I ran the c version of the Sample_mpio.c and it seems it worked:

Proc 2: all tests passed

Proc 3: all tests passed

Proc 1: all tests passed

Proc 0: all tests passed

So, the first step was configure:

```
CC=mpicc ./configure --enable-parallel --enable-shared
```

and then `make`

However, at some point `make` exited with several `SIG_SETMASK undeclared` error messages pointing to `sigsetjmp(J,N)` of the  `#define HDsigsetjmp(J,N)  sigsetjmp(J,N)` part followed by `in expansion of macro ...` for several macros.

Since there are no separate building instructions for cygwin, like for the serial case, I thought it might be an issue of cygwin.

What is the proper way to install parallel hdf5 (and h5py) on windows?

**Edit 1:**

Thanks to @varro 's suggestion, setting `make CFLAGS=-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE` resolved the error.

Nevertheless, now `make check` gives a segmentation fault...

```
Testing  testhdf5.exe
/bin/sh: line 30: 22284 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) srcdir="." ./${tname} >> ${log} 2>&1
```

Comment: What happens if instead of typing just `make` you type `make -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE`?

Comment: @varro I get `invalid option`. I have installed all devel packages from cygwin.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `make CFLAGS=-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE`

Comment: This resolved the `SIG_SETMASK` issue and `make` finished despite the big number of warnings. I will update the question, thanks a lot! Unfortunately, `make check` gives segmentation fault therefore I would like to keep the question open.

Comment: I got an answer from the hdf support that parallel hdf is neither tried nor supported, therefore I expect that installing it should be harder than expected.